# assign multiple value to javaScript array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

i have coded jQuery widget, which list all the record title in table which user can select of multiple records but with each record user to need to put value in text box.

now i want to built jQuery or JavaScript array where i can push record with each user click add and remove data if click remove against each button.

i want to push "recordId" & "ComponentSchemeMarks" to javaScript array selectedComponentList

[image]

```
var selectedComponentList = {
    componentIndex: "",
    componentMark:""
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    //click on Confirm Component Scheme 
    $("#ComponentSchemeTable").on("click", ".k-grid-confirm", function () {
        var recordId = $(this).data("id");
        var ComponentSchemeMarks = $("#" + recordId + "_CM").val();

        alert("recordId " + recordId + " ComponentSchemeMarks " + ComponentSchemeMarks);

        //
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-input").hide();
        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-cancel").hide();
        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-Remove").show();
        //add data to array//
    });

    $("#ComponentSchemeTable").on("click", ".k-grid-Remove", function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-Add").show();
    });
```

Comment: whats wrong with question, why i been mark down??

Comment: I think you are confusing arrays with objects. You can assign values to your object like this: `selectedComponentList.componentIndex = recordId;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selectedComponentList` is not an array... I guess you want something like this:

```
var selectedComponentArray = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    //click on Confirm Component Scheme 
    $("#ComponentSchemeTable").on("click", ".k-grid-confirm", function () {
        var recordId = $(this).data("id");
        var ComponentSchemeMarks = $("#" + recordId + "_CM").val();

        alert("recordId " + recordId + " ComponentSchemeMarks " + ComponentSchemeMarks);

        //
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-input").hide();
        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-cancel").hide();
        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-Remove").show();

        //add data to array//
        selectedComponentArray.push({ComponentIndex: recordId, ComponentMark: ComponentSchemeMarks});
    });

    $("#ComponentSchemeTable").on("click", ".k-grid-Remove", function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-Add").show();

        var recordId = $(this).data("id");

        selectedComponentArray = $.grep(selectedComponentArray, function(value) {
            return value.ComponentIndex != recordId;
        });
    });
    ...
}
```

Moreover you should give the buttons IDs and use them for binding the click listeners...